# TensorflowServing on a trained native Keras model with a preprocessing function for the input

Tags: python, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

My final goal is to use the What-If-Tool on tensorboard. In order to do that, I need to serve my Keras model on TensorflowServing, and the data in a TFRecordFile. So the data has to be transformed into tf.Examples.
The tool is supposed to grab the network to run inference on the data.
however, the network cannot handle tf.Examples as an input. So the served model needs to have a preprocessing function.

According to the tensorflow documentation, one way is to create a tensorflow Estimator, and to use "serving_input_receiver_fn" to preprocess the data. 
This would have been perfect except for the case that I can't make an already trained native Keras model into an Estimator. It seems that the only way it to create it from a tf.keras model (and not a native keras model like I have), and to train it directly with the estimator.

Another way would be to use the tf.saved_model.simple_save function, and then use TensorflowServing, but I did not find a way to preprocess the tf.Examples to make a correct input for the network.

Since this is not working, I have no clue on how to resolve this.

**Edit:** I tried to transform my native keras into a tf.keras model. My model is really big, so I build this function:

```
def create_tf_keras_model_from_native_keras(native_model):
    list_layers = []
    for i, layer in enumerate(native_model.layers):
        type_layer = str(layer).split('.')[2]
        second_type_layer = str(layer).split('.')[3].split(' ')[0]
        if type_layer == 'input_layer':
            new_layer = tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(**layer.get_config())
        elif type_layer == 'convolutional':
            new_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(**layer.get_config())
        elif type_layer == 'normalization':
            new_layer = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(**layer.get_config())
        elif type_layer == 'core':
            if second_type_layer == 'Activation':
                new_layer = tf.keras.layers.Activation(**layer.get_config())
            elif second_type_layer == 'Dense':
                new_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(**layer.get_config())
            elif second_type_layer == 'Dropout':
                new_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(**layer.get_config())
            elif second_type_layer == 'Lambda':
                config_lambda = layer.get_config()
                print(config_lambda)
                del config_lambda['function_type']
                del config_lambda['output_shape_type']
                new_layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(**config_lambda)
        elif type_layer == 'pooling':
            if second_type_layer == 'MaxPooling2D':
                new_layer = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(**layer.get_config())
            elif second_type_layer == 'AveragePooling2D':
                new_layer = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(**layer.get_config())
            elif second_type_layer == 'GlobalMaxPooling2D':
                new_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D(**layer.get_config())
        if new_layer == 'merge':
            new_layer = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(**layer.get_config())
        list_layers.append(new_layer)
    model = tf.keras.Sequential(list_layers)
    return model
```

However, this is not working because of Lambda layer. In the config layer, the function is now written in the form of:

```
'function': ('4wIAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAMAAABTAAAAcxQAAAB8AGQBGQB8AGQC8ARQAFwBTACkDTukAAAAA6QEA\nAACpACkC2gZpbaBXNjYWxlcgMAAAByAwAAAPp/L2dwZnMvaGFpZmEtcDYvMDMvbXNpZXZl\nX2RldjMvdXNyL3BhdWxkYS9naXRfcmVwb0hJLUltYWdlQW5hbHl0aWNzL3Jlc291cmNlcy9y\ndW5fMTE3NC9jdXN0b21fcHJldHJhaW5lZF9JbmNlcHRpb25SZXNOZXRWMi5wedoIPGxhbWJkYT6d\nAAAA8wAAAAA=\n', None, None)
```

Hence, I gave up this method hoping something else would allow to pre-process the input of my serving model.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Tensorflow Serving, in my opinion, it will be difficult to do it using Native Keras.

If you want to Prepare the Data ready for `Training` and `Serving`, you can perform the respective transformations using `Tensorflow Transform`.

But if you want to Prepare the Data only for `Serving`, The best way is the one mentioned by you, "*It seems that the only way it to create it from a tf.keras model (and not a native keras model like I have), and to train it directly with the estimator.*"

And you rightly said that it can't be done using `tf.saved_model.simple_save` function.

Example Code for creating Keras Model is shown below and converting it to `Estimator` is shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers
from tensorflow.python.keras import models

def get_keras_model():
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(INPUT_SHAPE,), name=INPUT_FEATURE)
    dense256 = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(inputs)
    dense32 = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(dense256)
    outputs = layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')(dense32)
    model = models.Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model
```

Then convert the Keras Model to Estimator using the below code:

```
classifier = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model, model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir)
```

For more information, refer the link,
https://github.com/yu-iskw/tensorflow-serving-example/blob/master/python/train/mnist_keras_estimator.py

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I answered you by adding an Edit to my original question (the number of characters allowed in a response was too low).